# Rearranging Dates in VB

Tags: mysql, vb.net, date

I am building a booking service in VB using Visual Studio 2012 and it uses a database. I was wondering how to rearrange dates from VB format ("MM-dd-yyyy") to MySQL date format ("yyyy-MM-dd"). Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Date.ToString` method allows you to specify a format:

```
Dim d = Date.Now
d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

However, it would be MUCH better to use a parameterized command using an actual `Date` variable and let the system convert for you, since the actual string format you need will depend on your current culture.  For instance:

```
Dim d = Date.Now
Using command As IDbCommand = connection.CreateCommand()
    command.CommandText = "UPDATE Table SET Column = @ColumnValue"
    Dim parameter As IDbDataParameter = command.CreateParameter()
    parameter.ParameterName = "@ColumnValue"
    parameter.Value = d
    command.Parameters.Add(parameter)
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```